# ora 22992 on a LOB field i am not using

Tags: oracle, blob

I have the following simple oracle query:

```
select A.field
from table1 A
left join table2@remotedb B on A.id = B.id
```

Where table B has a BLOB field

It runs fine

If i add a concat to the select:

```
select A.field||'x'
from table1 A
left join table2@remotedb B on A.id = B.id
```

I get the following error: 
"ora-22992 cannot use lob locators selected from remote tables"

Why adding a concat to a filed which isn't the LOB file is giving me this  error?!?

What can i do to avoid it?

Comment: What version of oracle you are using and what data type of `A.field` column? Cannot reproduce this behavior on 12c.

Comment: Which version of db do you have. Is it 11.2.0.3?

Comment: Unfortunately we have a really old version of oracle, like 9 or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### check this

```
with sub1 as
(
select /*+ materialize */ A.field
from table1 A
left join table2@remotedb B on A.id = B.id
)
select field || 'x'
from sub1
```

Comment: Good idea, it works in a subquery. Howerver it's a shame that we have to do this to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into similar issue. It seems Oracle requires it must be **guaranteed** any work with clob is avoided at remote side.

Assuming `@remotedb` is db link to another Oracle db, consider this minimized case:

```sql
select dummy from dual;                   -- works

select to_clob(dummy) from dual;          -- works

select dummy from dual@remotedb;          -- works

select to_clob(dummy) from dual@remotedb; -- fails - ORA-22992

with m as (select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ dummy from dual@remotedb)
select to_clob(dummy) from m;             -- works again, fails without hint
```

I also tried to find workaround based on forcing computation to local db (`select /*+DRIVING_SITE(local)*/ to_clob(r.dummy) from dual local, dual@remotedb r`) but with no success.